# How to change an action bar title text when moving from one tab to another tabs in nativescript

Tags: angular2-routing, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

- When loading this mainactivity page for the first time, it is loading
  the third tab page action bar text.
- I need to load the action bar text based on clicking the tab.
- For Eg: When I click the second tab means second tab action bar have
  to get trigger.

**main.activity.html:**

```
<ActionBar title="MainActivity" class="action-bar">

</ActionBar>


<TabView selectedIndex="0" (selectedIndexChange)="onIndexChanged($event)"  iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysTemplate" selectedTabTextColor="blue" sdkExampleTitle sdkToggleNavButton>
<TabView iosIconRenderingMode="alwaysOriginal"></TabView>

<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'First Tab',iconSource:'res://store'}" >
<first-page></first-page>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Second Tab',iconSource:'res://myapps'}" >
<second-page></second-page>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Third Tab',iconSource:'res://home'}" >
<third-page></third-page>
</StackLayout>

</TabView>
```

**main.activity.ts:**

```
public onIndexChanged(args) {
        let tabView = <TabView>args.object;
        console.log("Selected index changed! New inxed: " + tabView.selectedIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every tab position, we need to add the tabindex and add the title for appropriate page.

```
   <ActionBar *ngIf="tabIndex == 1" title="My Apps" color="black"> </ActionBar>
```